# "Rectangle with 3 straight lines" vs "rectangle using 3 straight lines"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

How do the three sentences below differ in meaning, and which can be answered with 'yes'?

> 1. Can you draw a rectangle with 3 straight lines?
> 2. Can you draw a rectangle by using 3 straight lines?
> 3. Can you draw a rectangle using 3 straight lines?

Comment: This would be a better question on the sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), methinks. There's not much here to challenge the serious linguist, but there might be much to explain to the non-native learner.

Comment: @J.R. : Migrate?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy migration system in place yet. But, if we make the comment, at least you'll know about ELL's existence (many folks aren't even aware of the ELL site yet). That knowledge gives you two options: ask some of your later questions there – if those questions would be a better fit at that site – or re-ask this one there, if it gets closed here before you get satisfactory answers.

Comment: Strange, I edited the question, RegDwight took the credits. I wonder how that happens

Comment: @StewardGodwinJornsen  Seven minutes after your edit, RegDwight performed another edit. You may examine the edit history by clicking on the time which appears after the word "edited".

Comment: Why was this question edited (other than by the OP)? It ought to be migrated (closed & moved). Inquisitive: If wait patiently, you may find the question moving over to ELL.

Comment: This Facebook thing. I was looking for a like for your comment. @StoneyB . In any case, my sentence was: *How do the below three sentences differ in their meaning and which HAS the answer 'yes'?* I don't seem to see how "which ALL have the answer yes" work better. In any case, explanations taken.

Comment: I was also wondering why it was edited and then down voted, were they down voting the edit or the question before it was edited?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a rectangle cannot be drawn using 3 straight lines. That can only form a triangle. But 3 straight lines are amongst what makes up a rectangle, so with 3 straight lines, a rectangle can come close to being created. So I'd go with 1)

I can draw an incomplete rectangle WITH 3 straight lines. No I can't draw a rectangle USING 3 straight lines.

I can build a house with bricks (does not mean only bricks are required. Bricks are just some components like the 3 lines forming a rectangle). What I can't do is build a complete house with brick (I'd need wood for windows and roofing sheets). It would incorrect for me to say, I can build a house using bricks (this means bricks is all I'd possibly need to build that house and can complete it with nothing else).

So with might not mean the component is complete, but indicates that is is a major portion of the components required. In multiples, I could build a house with bricks and woods as against, I can build a house using bricks and woods.

Oops! *still sounds silly, but that's how I see it!* :(

Comment: No probs with the down votes, but I'd learn if I know why. Thanks

Comment: Steward, as a free service I have migrated you answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/rectangle-with-3-straight-lines-vs-rectangle-using-3-straight-lines/3420#3420) where you could have more upvotes.

Comment: I noticed that, thanks greatly. I also saw the answer in the link provided. Marvellous. We are all learning in some way.